# How to initialize ST7789S for RGB connection to LTDC peripheral from STM32

Tags: debugging

Guys I have an issue initializing ST7789S LCD driver for RGB connection.

IM0: 0; IM1: 1; IM2: 1; DOT clock: 7MHz.
Also this is my LTDC configuration:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
void ST7789_Init(void)
{
    ST7789_CS_Set();
     HAL_Delay(20);
     ST7789_CS_Clr();
     HAL_Delay(20);

    ST7789_RST_Set();
    HAL_Delay(200);
    ST7789_RST_Clr();
    HAL_Delay(200);
    ST7789_RST_Set();
    HAL_Delay(200);

    /*FRAME RATE SETTING*/
    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xb2);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x0c);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x0c);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x00);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x33);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x33);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xb7);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x35);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0x3a);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x55); //18 RGB ,55-16BIT RGB

    //--------------------ST7789S Power setting--------//

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xbb);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x30);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xc3);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x1c);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xc4);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x18);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xc6);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x0f);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xd0);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0xa4);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0xa2);

    /*ST7789S gamma setting*/

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xe0);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0xf0);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x00);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x0a);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x10);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x12);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x1b);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x39);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x44);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x47);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x28);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x12);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x10);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x16);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x1b);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xe1);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0xf0);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x00);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x0a);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x10);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x11);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x1a);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x3b);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x34);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x4e);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x3a);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x17);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x16);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x21);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x22);


    //*********SET RGB Interfae***************
    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xB0);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x11); //set RGB interface and DE mode.
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0xC2);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0xB1);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x40); //set DE mode.
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x04);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x0A);

    ST7789_WriteCommand(0x3a);
    ST7789_WriteSmallData(0x55); //18 RGB ,55-16BIT RGB

    ST7789_WriteCommand (ST7789_SLPOUT);    //  Out of sleep mode
    HAL_Delay(120);
    ST7789_WriteCommand (ST7789_NORON);     //  Normal Display on
    ST7789_WriteCommand (ST7789_DISPON);    //  Main screen turned on
    ST7789_WriteCommand (0x2c);
    ST7789_WriteCommand (0xff);
    HAL_Delay(50);
}
```

Comment: You don't use the LTDC module with an "intelligent" display. You connect your display as an external parallel memory device (possibly using the FMC module). The LTDC is for "raw" displays which need to be driven with RGB signals.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for your explanation. There are some explanations regarding RGB interface selection in its datasheet. Even the hardware connection is equal to LTDC pinout. This is the link to the data sheet:
https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/33/ST7789.pdf  page 107 this is explained.

Comment: Do you want to strictly use RGB mode and not a 16-bit MCU parallel interface (using FMC) ? If so, what is the problem you're encountering ? Please edit your post with what's not working.

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2790-tft-lcd-interfacing-with-the-highdensity-stm32f10xxx-fsmc-stmicroelectronics.pdf a useful application note if you want to use a parallel interface with FMC (which is easier than using RGB mode)

Comment: Ok, you could use it that way - but do you have the GPIO pins correctly configured at the right times? If you've used CubeMX to set it up in LTDC mode then all your `ST7789_WriteCommand` calls will not work since they'll be trying to drive the pins as if they're in GPIO mode. You'll have to do all your `ST7789_Init` code with the pins configured in GPIO mode and then switch over to the LTDC.

Comment: A 6800/8080 parallel interface is a different thing from an RGB interface which LTDC is made to be used for. The 6800/8080 interface here is used to communicate with ST7789 chip and the chip communicates with its attached RGB display. LTDS is made for displays without a controller chip where the MCU has to do what ST7789 for example, does for that particular display.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad it looks the the ST7789 allows you to switch it out of 'smart' parallel mode into 'dumb' RBG mode - which seems to be what the OP wants to do. But I suspect that all the STM32's port pins going to the LCD are already configured for 'dumb' RGB mode for the LTDC - which would prevent sending commands to the ST7789 to tell it to switch modes. –

Comment: My ultimate goal is to make a graphic user interface with the help of TouchGFX, and for that it is easier for me to use LTDC peripheral